# When I call a function within a function it skips code and terminates program?

Tags: c++, function, gcc, udf

*It is a big program. I stripped off unnecessary code. I left only one of the key functions*

When I call `ss();` in any function the function gives control back to `main()` without accepting a string.
The code works if I don't use a function to accept the string. I can't find anything wrong with it.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>
void ss();
void casechange();
using namespace std;
char str[100];
int main (){
int choice;

cout<<"Make a choice"<<endl; 
cout<<"Press 1 to change the case of alphabets"<<endl;
cout<<"Press 2 to count number of vowels"<<endl;
cout<<"Press 3 to check if entered string is a palindrome or not"<<endl;
cout<<"Press 4 to reverse a string"<<endl;
cout<<"Press 5 to count number of words"<<endl;
cin>>choice;
switch(choice){
case 1: casechange();
    break; 
case 2: vowelcount();
        break;
case 3:pal();
    break;
case 4: rev();
    break;
case 5: wordcount();
    break;
default: cout<<"Wrong choice"<<endl;
 }
 return 0;
}
void casechange(){
ss();
for(int i=0;str[i]!='\0';i++)
 {
 if(isupper(str[i]))
 str[i]=tolower(str[i]);
 else str[i]=toupper(str[i]);
 }
 puts(str);
}
void ss()
{
cout<<"Enter a string"<<endl;
 gets(str);
}
```

p.s. I am using code blocks. gcc compiler I guess.

Comment: (1) You're mixing C standard I/O with C++ standard streams.   It works, but it is bad style.  (2) You're using C `gets()`; that would be an instant failure were I in charge of your code.  It is a lethal function that cannot be used safely in any code.  You may get away with it for a while, but not for ever.  (3) Your problem is almost certainly that the first input leaves a newline in the input buffer, and the `gets()` call in `ss()` reads that newline and finishes.  There are a lot of questions with the same basic problem.

Comment: You are currently mixing C++-style input (cin) and C-style input (gets). I'd wager that's the issue here. My recommendation would be to switch to just using C++-style input. Then, switch from using raw char arrays to using `std::string`, which is easier to use and less error-prone.

Comment: Also, please study how to create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  You've done a fairly good job, but you could eliminate the options other than `casechange()` to make it (a) more minimal and (b) self-contained so it can be compiled and tested.  (See also: SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — a similar exposition to the MCVE one.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks I am new here. I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked user to make a choice. User typed a number **and** `enter`. You then read a single character. `enter` still sitting there in the buffer. When it comes to `gets`, it reads it as an empty string.

Also please pay attention to all the comments about IO, `gets` etc.